# How can I publish an image from url with Twitter API?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to publish an image from URL with Twitter API and PHP but I can't do it.
I have seeked in many post but I could find only how to upload an image.
Is possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, this is *not* possible.

One way around it is for you to download the image first, and then upload it.

For example

```
file_put_contents("temp-img.jpg", file_get_contents("http://example.com/flower.jpg"));
```

Then, using whichever Twitter library you have, you can post `temp-img.jpg`directly.